# MVP, testing, and private methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, mvp

I've switched to an MVP architecture and am trying to test it.  I have some question on how to structure my Presenter.

```
public class Presenter
{
    public void onResume()
    {
        doA();
        doB();
        doC();
    }

    protected void doA() {};
    protected void doB() {};
    protected void doC() {};
}

public class MyScreen implements MyScreenView
{
    private Presenter presenter;

    public MyScreen()
    {
        presenter = new Presenter(this);
    }

    public OnResume()
    {
        presenter.OnResume();
    }
}
```

In the above code, when the view is resumed, the view simply calls the presenter OnResume().  The presenter internally calls 3 methods, doA(), doB(), and doC() to do whatever it has to do.

Alternatively, I can just call doA(), doB() and doC() in the view directly like so:

```
public class Presenter
{
    public void doA() {};
    public void doB() {};
    public void doC() {};
}

public class MyScreen implements MyScreenView
{
    private Presenter presenter;

    public MyScreen()
    {
        presenter = new Presenter(this);
    }

    public OnResume()
    {
        presenter.doA();
        presenter.doB();
        presenter.doC();
    }
}
```

My question is, its easier for me to test the second solution, since the presenter is cleanly broken up into 3 seperate public methods of individual responsibility, I can write tests for doA, doB and doC individually instead of one monolithic test for the presenter.onResume() method of solution 1.

In the first solution, I have to write tests for onResume(), which has a combined responsibility of calling these 3 methods.  This means its harder to test, as its much easier to test smaller functions of individual responsibility than functions that call other private functions.  However, the second solution doesn't feel like a good MVP in my belief, since it seems to know what the presenter is doing and is just not letting the presenter do what it should do in the onResume() method of the first solution.

Comment: Never ask for opinions on stackoverflow. Its a guarantee to get the question closed. Of course everything that is worth a up or downvotes is opinion, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your MyScreen class to

```
public class MyScreen implements MyScreenView
{
    private presenter;

    public MyScreen()
    {
        presenter = new Presenter();
    }

    public MyScreen(Presenter p) 
    {
        presenter = p;
    }

    public OnResume()
    {
        presenter.OnResume();
    }
}
```

then you have a production constructor which creates a new Presenter and a convenience constructor for testing so you can instantiate it with a Mock presenter. I prefer Mockito (code from memory so...)

```
Presenter mockP = Mock(Presenter.class);
MyScreen target = new MyScreen(mockP);
target.OnResume();
verify(mockP).doA();
verify(mockP).doB();
verify(mockP).doC();
```

Here you create a new MyScreen with a Mock Presenter. When you call verify on the various methods your test will fail if that method was never called on the mock. So you are in effect writing a test that asserts if you call OnResume on the MyScreen class the effect is to call doA, doB and doC on its presenter field.

You can specify what arguments you expect when you verify the method was called. And you can stub the methods of mockP so that it will return known results in particular scenarios.

---

Incidentally

```
public OnResume()
    {
        presenter.OnResume();
    }
```

is IMHO the better choice of your two options because then you can change what the `presenter.OnResume()` method does without having to change the MyScreen class.

Comment: hrm....can I call verify(mockP).doA() if doA() is private?

Comment: No, then you'd verify the onResume method of Presenter was called. When you're testing the Presenter class you could test that if onResume is called the stuff those three do methods..er... ... do is done. I've got a feeling that PowerMock can deal with private methods but I've never used powerMock so could very easily be wrong

Answer (score 1):

First make the presenter injectable in the My Screen class

```
public class MyScreen implements MyScreenView
{
    private presenter;

    public MyScreen()
    {
        presenter = this(new Presenter());
    }

    public MyScreen(Presenter p) 
    {
        presenter = p;
    }

    public OnResume()
    {
        presenter.OnResume();
    }
}
```

Now you can test the behavior of MyScreen by injecting a mock.

```
Presenter mockP = Mock(Presenter.class);
MyScreen target = new MyScreen(mockP);
target.OnResume();
verify(mockP).doA();
verify(mockP).doB();
verify(mockP).doC();
```

In a completely separate test you can test the presenter:

```
Presenter presenter = new Presenter();
presenter.onResume();
assertEquals("some State that should be true after calling on resume", presenter.getSomeMagicState());
```

Do not test that onResume calls doA, doB and doC, test the behavior of the method, by checking angainst the state of the presenter.

If whatever doX does gets to complicated, extract it into a seperate class, test that, inject it into the presenter and test that it gets called.